# jQuery convert clicked tag to string

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-events

How to convert clicked tag to string and pass to textarea:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <textarea name="button_code">
        Here should be pasted actual code from clicked tag:
    </textarea>
</div>
<button class=insert name=insert>Insert</button>
```

I try with but no success (not working):

```
var pos = 0;
$('textarea').click(function() {
    var pos = $(this).attr("name");
    return false;
});

$('.insert').click(function() {
var tt = $(this).prop('outerHTML');
var str = new String(tt);
    $('textarea[name^="' + pos + '"]').insertAtCaret('' + str + '');
});
```

I get the button in string but, it`s not pasting in textarea....

Comment: SOLVED ... http://jsfiddle.net/ArtofLife/u9d9d/

Comment: In FF, it shows 'undefined' in the textarea

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a custom function to get the attr list and append with tagName to get the complete HTML element that is passed to the function.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/u9d9d/28/) here

```
function getHTMLElementAsStr(el) {

    var attr, attrs;       
    var elNodeName = el.nodeName.toLowerCase();
    var elTmpl = '<' + elNodeName + '{ATTR_LIST}>' + el.innerHTML + '</' + elNodeName + '>';

    var result = '';
    for (var i=0, attrs=el.attributes, l=attrs.length; i<l; i++){
        attr = attrs.item(i);

        //i assume that you don't need quotes for attr value.. if needed.. modify this line as needed
        result += ' ' + attr.nodeName + '=' + attr.nodeValue;
    }

    result = elTmpl.replace (/{ATTR_LIST}/, result);

    return result;       
}
```